# iPhone MapKit error

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, google-maps, mapkit

I just started the use of Mapkit Framework.
I got a sample code from [here](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2009/04/02/iphone-sdk-30-playing-with-map-kit/).

But when I build the code it returns the following error.

```
/SourceCache/GoogleMobileMaps/GoogleMobileMaps-201/googlenav/mac/Loader.mm:195 server returned error: 407
```

It does not shows the map.

I am confused whether the code has an error or there is some error with Google services.

Comment: Have you included the MapKit framework? At what point does this error happen?

Comment: In case you don't know where to look it up: Error 407 means "Proxy Authentication Required".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution, we need to add  Credentials to user's keychain
here is my code

```
NSURLCredentialStorage * credentialStorage=[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage]; //(1)
NSURLCredential * newCredential;
newCredential=[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"myUserName" password:@"myPWD" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent]; //(2)
NSURLProtectionSpace * mySpaceHTTP=[[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc] initWithProxyHost:@"ipProxy" port:port type:NSURLProtectionSpaceHTTPProxy realm:nil authenticationMethod:nil]; //(3)
NSURLProtectionSpace * mySpaceHTTPS=[[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc] initWithProxyHost:@"ipProxy" port:port type:NSURLProtectionSpaceHTTPSProxy realm:nil authenticationMethod:nil]; //(4)
[credentialStorage setCredential:newCredential forProtectionSpace:mySpaceHTTP]; //(5)
[credentialStorage setCredential:newCredential forProtectionSpace:mySpaceHTTPS]; //(6)
```

I recovered  first the sharedCredentialStorage (1), then i created new NSURLCredential containing my user name, password, and the type
of persistence to use (2) . After that I created two NSURLProtectionSpace (3)(4): one for  HTTPS  Connexion, and one for HTTP Connexion

And finally, i added NSURLCredential  the sharedCredentialStorage for these ProtectionSpaces (5)(6)

I hope that this code can help you

Answer (score 0):

Yes we have included Mapkit framework.After viewDidLoad error is coming ,don't have exact idea from which delegate method is giving this error